# How to apply WHERE clause to multiple SELECT statements in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, date, select, where-clause

I am creating an query that selects data from multiple tables. I have completed all the query but now I have to apply the `WHERE` clause to the whole query.
I have 9 select statements, and these are working fine. Data is being selected from different tables. Now I want to declare date `session` and I want all data to be filtered according to the date provided. I am using the below query:

```
SELECT 
    (SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT OrderItems.ProductID)
     FROM OrderItems) AS 'TotalSoldItemsDistinct', 
    (SELECT COUNT(OrderItems.ProductID)
     FROM OrderItems) AS 'TotalSoldItemsInDistinct',
    (SELECT COUNT(Orders.OrderID)
     FROM Orders) AS 'TotalOrders', 
   (SELECT COUNT(Orders.OrderID)
    FROM Orders
    WHERE Orders.OrderStatusID = @CompleteOStatusID) AS 'CompleteOrders', 
   (SELECT COUNT(Orders.OrderID)
    FROM Orders
    WHERE Orders.OrderStatusID = @PendingOStatusID) AS 'PendingOrders', 
   (SELECT COUNT(Orders.ClientID)
    FROM Orders
    WHERE Orders.ClientID != @WalkingCustID) AS 'namedcustomers',
   (SELECT COUNT(Orders.ClientID)
    FROM Orders
    WHERE Orders.ClientID = @WalkingCustID) AS 'WalkingCustomers',
   (SELECT SUM(OrderItems.PurchasePrice)
    FROM OrderItems) AS 'TotalPurchasePrice',
   (SELECT SUM(OrderItems.SalePrice) 
    FROM OrderItems) AS 'TotalSalePrice'
```

I am selecting data from 2 tables named '`Orders`' and '`OrderItems`', I have column `TransactionDate` in 'Orders' table and column `OrderDate` in `OrderItems` table on that I want to use where filter. Can anybody please suggest how to apply filter to whole query?

Comment: there's more than solving your problem here.. your queries can be more simplified

Comment: thanks for reply. will u please suggest me how to do that ?

Comment: you'll have to look for a similar case or wait until someone because i'm going home now :)

Comment: will u please tell me how to apply date filter on whole query?

Comment: ok when u get home, post reply here. waiting..

Comment: This can be rewritten without subqueries. You can put the two tables in the main query, but unclear if they can be joined - need more information. From there in your SELECT use `COUNT(CASE WHEN THEN ELSE null END)` type queries. Still hard to write something to help you without knowing the relationship if any between the two tables.

Answer (score 1):

You could try this

```
;with tempOrderItems AS
   (   
      SELECT  
         COUNT(DISTINCT OrderItems.ProductID) AS 'TotalSoldItemsDistinct',
         COUNT(OrderItems.ProductID) AS 'TotalSoldItemsInDistinct',
         SUM(OrderItems.PurchasePrice) AS 'TotalPurchasePrice',
         SUM(OrderItems.SalePrice)  AS 'TotalSalePrice'
      FROM OrderItems ori
      WHERE OrderDate  BETWEEN xxx AND yyy
   )
, tempOrders AS
   (
      SELECT 
         COUNT(o.OrderID) AS 'TotalOrders',
         SUM(CASE WHEN o.OrderStatusID = @CompleteOStatusID THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS 'CompleteOrders', 
         SUM(CASE WHEN o.OrderStatusID = @PendingOStatusID THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS 'PendingOrders', 
         SUM(CASE WHEN o.ClientID != @WalkingCustID THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS 'namedcustomers', 
         SUM(CASE WHEN o.ClientID = @WalkingCustID THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS 'WalkingCustomers'
      FROM Orders o
      WHERE TransactionDate BETWEEN xxx AND yyy

   )   
SELECT * FROM tempOrderItems 
CROSS JOIN tempOrders
```

Answer (score 0):

It is not fully clear what you want as a result, but here 2 approaches.

1. Try the following for selecting data from 2 tables at the same time (replace the date with your criteria):

   `SELECT * FROM Orders AS o INNER JOIN OrderItems AS i WHERE o.TransactionDate = '2015-02-12' AND i.OrderDate = '2015-02-12';`

The `SELECT *` selects all columns from both tables as a result and the `WHERE ... AND ...`-clause filters for results only with your defined date.

2. Try the following for selecting order item data only for Data that matches the date on a specific order.

   `SELECT i.* FROM Orders AS o INNER JOIN OrderItems AS i WHERE o.TransactionDate = i.OrderDate AND o.OrderID = '12345';`

The `SELECT i.*` tells the query to only return the columns of the OrderItems. And the `WHERE o.TransactionDate = i.OrderDate` ensures that only order items from the same date of the order with the OrderID "12345" are returned (which is defined with the `AND o.OrderID = '12345'`. This would work given you have a field "OrderID" on your Order table and you want to use it as a criteria.